# C# - Why HttpClient PostAsync blocks in .exe, but works with Visual Studio 2015 -> Debug?

Tags: c#, post, cookies, visual-studio-2015, httpclient

I have a C# Console Application that has to create an HttpClient and make some request to our "3CX Phone System Management" web portal (I have to retrieve/change our employees phone status). To do that I have to login, save the received cookies into a CookieContainer and then going on with other requests that has to use the same cookies. Here the code:

```
public static CookieContainer cookies = null;
public static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Task.Run(() => ExtListAsync());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<bool> LoginAsync() {
    try {
        cookies = new CookieContainer();
        handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false)) {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my.uri.com:5001");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            StringContent parameters = new StringContent(@"{""key"":""value"",""key2"":""value2""}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // BLOCKS HERE....
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/other", parameters).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content) {
                    string responseContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();

                    if (responseCookies.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (HttpRequestException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r EXCEPTION MESSAGE: " + ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r DATA: " + ex.Data);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r InnerException: " + ex.InnerException);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r Source: " + ex.Source);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\r TargetSite: " + ex.TargetSite);
        return true;
    }
}

static async Task ExtListAsync() {
    bool loggedIn = await LoginAsync();
    if (loggedIn) { ... }
}
```

I have this simple code, that launched with the Visual Studio "Start Debugging" executes correctly.
If I try to launch the .exe from my command prompt (tried also with Admin mode), sometimes the application executes correctly with a little delay, but for most of the times it remains blocked on "await client.PostAsync(...)"... , and then trows an HttpRequestException:

```
EXCEPTION MESSAGE: An error occurred while sending the request.

 DATA: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

 InnerException: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5001
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

 Source: mscorlib

 StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at statusmng3cx.Program.<LoginAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in ...\myPath\Program.cs:line 254

 TargetSite: Void Throw()
```

Someone has an explanation for that? 
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried to add the SSL certificate:

```
WebRequestHandler whandler = new WebRequestHandler();
whandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

var pem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("mycert.pem");
byte[] certBuffer = GetBytesFromPEM(pem, "CERTIFICATE");
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBuffer);

whandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(whandler)) { ... as above ... }
```

And happens the same thing: via Debug it works perfectly:
Status Code 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', responseContent: AuthSuccess, ...

And via prompt the .exe won't collaborate.. But if I change the 3CX Portal URL to another simple website, which retrieves a static webpage (without SSL), the .exe works perfectly.

Comment: Are you setting any required request headers? Is there an SSL forward in place on the server?

Comment: Actually no, but if I try to replicate the same POST/GET request with Postman, it works well without any SSL header or certificate. I've sniffed these request with the Chrome Network inspector.

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler? it's definitely odd that it works in debug/Postman but not when run via exe. Out of curiousity, are you building for Release at all?

Comment: I didn't tried with Fiddler yet.. But I've tried to build it in debug/release for any combination of x64/Any CPU.. The first 2-3 times it works, then it throws HttpRequestException.
The server is our "3CX Phone System Management" portal, and I have to retrieve our employees status..

Comment: @Jakasha It is because you are mixing blocking calls (`.Result`) within async/await which can lead to deadlocks. Code needs to be async all the way through.

Comment: @Nkosi I've tried to print on the console some text to see if it oversteps the "await client.PostAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false)" It blocks before the .Result call :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have written the program in Java and it works perfectly from console.

```
    try {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };

        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy);
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()).setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();


        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(mainUrl + loginUrl);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("myJson");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, context);

        System.out.println("Response getStatusLine: " + 

        response.getStatusLine());
    } catch (...) { ... }
```

And the output:

```
Response getStatusLine: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```